# minLength doesn't work in typescript, react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an input in Next, typescript. Maxlength does work but minlength doesn't work now. Does anyone how to validate this both?

Here's my code.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="text" required={true} minLength={2} maxLength={10} />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Try putting `required="required"` on it.

Comment: If I replace `required={true}` with `requied="required"`, TypeError happens.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. However `minlength` works different than `maxlength`.

- HTML `maxlength` prevents the user from typing keys more than the maxlength.
- HTML `minlength` will let the user enter less keys compared to the requirement. After all, they need to be able to start from less chars to come up to more chars. That said the field will show an error if minlenght is not met.

## Complete example

Use this component and press the enter key to play around with the input field:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="text" required={true} minLength={2} maxLength={10} />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  );
}
```

## Screenshots

Because its required:
[image]

Because minlenght is not met:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

use can install Material ui Libraries `npm install @material-ui/core` [Material ui Libraries](https://material-ui.com/)

There have lots of components. use Textfield components .
 Using **inputProps** we set maxlength in textfield

```
<TextField inputProps={{ maxLength: 10 }} type="text" />
```

[Material Ui Textfied Compoents](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#text-field)

Answer (score 0):

I've got an obscure solution which may or may not relate to what the OP was experiencing.

In my case, the tooltip-like error wasn't showing for an invalid `minLength` value because I had applied `.toUpperCase()` on the state, like so:

```
// PROBLEM
<input
  required
  name="guess-input"
  type="text"
  value={guess}
  minLength={5}
  maxLength={5}
  onChange={(event) => {
    const nextGuess = event.target.value.toUpperCase(); //<-- the culprit
    setGuess(nextGuess);
  }}
></input>
```

Apparently, that won't validate letters that have been transformed to upper.

**As a solution**, I dropped that method and added a style attribute like so:

```
// SOLUTION
<input
  required
  name="guess-input"
  type="text"
  value={guess}
  minLength={5}
  maxLength={5}
  style={{ textTransform: "uppercase" }}
  onChange={(event) => {
    const nextGuess = event.target.value;
    setGuess(nextGuess);
  }}
></input>
```

*Not shown is the rest of the markup for the form.*

And in a function outside of the return, I passed set another variable equal to state and converted what it received. Because strings are immutable, I wouldn't have to worry about any mutation issues for state.

Here's that function:

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent a submitted form from reloading the page

  let upperGuess = guess.toUpperCase; // new pointer to an upper version of state

  console.log({ upperGuess }); // see the new upper version

  setGuess(""); // reset the input to empty
    }
```

**References:**

- [MDN article on toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)