# Minlength doesn't work when I add onChange property

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to prevent using special symbols except - in input and check the min-length and max-length. But When I add onChange property on input tag, the minLength property doesn't work!(maxLength works fine.)

Does anyone how to solve this?

```
    const handleNickname = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let allowedNick = e.target.value;
    allowedNick = allowedNick.replace(/ /gi, "");
    allowedNick = allowedNick.replace(
      /[~\-+=!?@#$%₩^&*|(){}\[\]\\\/'";:<>,]/gi,
      ""
    );
    e.target.value = allowedNick;
    setNick(allowedNick);
  };
    <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="text" required={true} minLength={2} maxLength={10} onChange={handleNickname} />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: i suggest you to use a third-party library like react-hook-form to validate inputs. it's much simpler to work with and has some helpers that makes world a better place!
btw, your question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69157200/minlength-doesnt-work-in-typescript-react

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20161 from GitHub issues i also can see the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are manually changing the value, and for some reason this is messing with the form submission validator.
This line breaks - `e.target.value = allowedNick;`
Making component controlled solved this for me.

```
export function Test() {
    const [text, setText] = useState('') // added state
    const handleNickname = (e) => {
        
        let allowedNick = e.target.value;
        allowedNick = allowedNick.replace(/ /gi, "");
        allowedNick = allowedNick.replace(
          /[~\-+=!?@#$%₩^&*|(){}\[\]\\\/'";:<>,]/gi,
          ""
        );
        setText(allowedNick) // changing state
      };
      return  <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="text" onChange={handleNickname} required={true} minLength={2} maxLength={10} value={text} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
}
```